# Java Class Relationship and ORM

Tags: java, relationship

I have this simple login-registration functionality using the following classes.

User class:

```
public class User implements Serializable {
    private int userId;
    private String username;
    private String password;

    public User() {
        userId = 0;
        username = "";
        password = "";
    }

    // public set-get methods here
}
```

Verification class:

```
public class Verification implements Serializable {
    private int userId;
    private String code;
    private long expirationDate; // millis

    public Verification() {
        userId = 0;
        code = "";
        expirationDate = 0;
    }

    public void setUserId(int Id) {
        userId = Id;
    }

    public void setUserId(User user) {
        userId = user.getUserId();
    }

    // the rest of set-get methods here
}
```

I would like to confirm if the relationship above is considered Dependency? or Association?

Also, I'm using this classes in ORM. Does omitting one setUserId() overloaded method mess up the relationship between(if there's any)? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would say a dependency exists between Verification and User, as you can pass a User reference to a method of Verification (it uses that reference and depends on it), but Verification instance does not OWN a reference to a User instance, instead it consumes one.

Comment: If I make User an instance variable for Verification then add set-get methods for it, that would make an Association / Aggregation, right?

Comment: Right. Depending on the tightness of the coupling between the instances (as in, do you hold a reference to an already existing User or will each Verification instance instantiate its own User object)

Answer (score 0):

The example you gave , describes dependency .

For reference you can visit the link given below -:

https://nirajrules.wordpress.com/2011/07/15/association-vs-dependency-vs-aggregation-vs-composition/

Comment: Thank you. I'm a bit confused on Association and Aggregation though.